# Updating combination of three elements in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if it is possible to make an update in one column using information from other 3. Like I have some sort of grocery database more detailed - table (order), I wish to make a new column - SUM. I also have price of a product and products are divided in two classes - quantity in kg and quantity in piecies. When I make Update like this:

```
UPDATE Order
SET Sum=Storage.Price*Order.Q_piece
FROM Storage, Order
WHERE Storage.ProductID=Order.ProductID
```

The update applies to all quantity - piece products and sets `NULL` value to kg products, if I set up update for `Q_kg products`, `Q_piece` products automatically sets to `NULL` and something like this doesn't exactly work.

```
UPDATE Order
SET Sum=Storage.Price*Order.Q_piece AND/OR Sum=Storage.Price*Order.Q_kg
FROM Storage, Order
WHERE Storage.ProductID=Order.ProductID
```

Any solutions or it's not possible in one column ?

Comment: you need to update 1 column using 3 column data?

Comment: @DreamerXD Yes, create SUM of Price*Q_kg and Price*Q_piece, where both will never be in same row.

Comment: what is the name of the column that display the result ?

Comment: @DreamerXD SUM, where is information about Price*Q_kg and Price*Q_piece

Comment: please do check my answer.

Comment: If you have a piece quantity product, what value has Q_kg and vice versa?

Comment: @MartinK. its set `NULL` but now I think that the solution would be setting it to `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an additional condition to your where clauses.

```
UPDATE Order
SET Sum=Storage.Price*Order.Q_piece
FROM Storage, Order
WHERE Storage.ProductID=Order.ProductID
    AND Order.Q_piece is not null
```

The same statement for the Q_kg products.

As long as you use NULL values, which is correct in my opinion, every calculation will return NULL too.

Update:
Mysql supports case statements, so something like following should do too:

```
UPDATE Order
SET Sum=Storage.Price*CASE WHEN Order.Q_piece is not null THEN Order.Q_piece ELSE Order.Q_kg END
FROM Storage, Order
WHERE Storage.ProductID=Order.ProductID
```

Comment: Except Sum is calculated using Q_piece and Q_kg in one column

Comment: Sum is an aggregate, id don't see how this should help

Comment: This did actually work had to apply two updates where one was with Q_piece other was with Q_kg, i guess condition `Order.Q_piece IS NOT NULL` was the key.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Order
SET sum= sum(S.Price*O.Q_piece) + sum (S.Price*O.Q_kg)
FROM Storage S 
inner join Order O
on S.ProductID=O.ProductID
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near column. I tried `SET SUM=((S.Price*O.Q_piece)+(S.price*Q_kg))` But prints out `NULL`

Comment: sum= sum((S.Price*O.Q_piece)+(S.price*Q_kg))

Comment: sum = sum(S.Price*O.Q_piece) + sum (S.Price*O.Q_piece)

Comment: I think i should just set empty column `Q_piece` and `Q_kg` values to `0` instead of `NULL` dont you think ?

Comment: `An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.`

Comment: what is the value of Q piece and Q kg? I already Update my answer try to execute again

Comment: For example Q_piece VALUES ('5',NULL,NULL) and Q_kg VALUES (NULL,'1.1','2.2')

Comment: @DreamerXD, adding a point to your answer. Order is mysql reserved word, to use it as table name or column name always use `Order`

Comment: The table name is actually in my language `pasutijums` i just translated to make it more understandable for you.

Comment: What is the result of the my answer?

Comment: its `An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.`